# How downcasts and upcasts are preformed? And how the types are compared? How RTTI is usually stored?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, rtti, dynamic-cast

I've read about `RTTI`. The information written here may be wrong. It's just what I've understood.

1 - Each type has a pointer to it's base classes and a pointer to a string containing it's name. When donwcasting using `dynamic_cast` for example, it goes through the base classes and recurses until it find one that matches. Assuming that what I've said is true, what about upcasting? How it's done since each type has only a knowledge of it's base classes, how does it figure out it's subclasses?

2 - Also does it know whether the operation is a downcast or an upcast before actually casting? In other words, when I preform `dynamic_cast<SomeClass>`, does it try to find `SomeClass` in the entire hierarchy tree? Or does it know which direction to go (to search in the parents node or to search in the child nodes)? And if it does, then how?

3 - As far as I've understood, The type of each class is stored as a string and whenever someone uses `dynamic_cast`, it compares the strings of types until it finds the right class. If that's true, why this is done? Why not giving each class an integer ID at compile time and storing that ID instead of the string name. And whenever casting happens, just compare the two numbers. And let the type string of all classes be stored in an array somewhere (lets call it `typesArr`) and whenever actually needing to get the name of the class, just lookup `typesArr[ID]`. I think something like that is more intuitive and I'm missing something. So how actually is `RTTI` stored? I don't mean how it works. I mean if how is it represented in memory? I know that it's implementation dependent. But how is it stored usually in most compilers? And how types are actually compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Obligatory disclaimer: as already noted in the question, most of this is implementation specific, not general C++ rules.)

I think you may be using "upcast" and "downcast" reversed from what I'm used to.

But in any case, a conversion from a derived class pointer to base class pointer (or initializing a base class reference from a derived class glvalue) doesn't need to involve the RTTI "class tree" at all. The compiler knows all the base classes and the layout of the subobjects in the derived class. For a non-virtual base, the base subobject address is at a fixed offset from the derived object address. For a virtual base class, the offset to the base subobject depends on the object's most derived type, so the conversion involves looking up that offset in the vtable.

`dynamic_cast` is defined to just do the above derived-to-base cast if valid ([[expr.dynamic.cast]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.dynamic.cast#5)). Otherwise, yes, it searches for the base class in the entire tree of classes inherited by the object's complete type. The implementation of this search will probably start from the root: the most derived class. Note that derived-to-base and base-to-derived are not the only cases: `dynamic_cast` can also cast "sideways", to find a sibling/cousin/etc. subobject.

```
struct A { virtual ~A(); int m; };
struct B { virtual ~B(); int n; };

int f(const A& a) {
    // Valid, even though there's no inheritance relation between
    // A and B at all:
    auto& b = dynamic_cast<const B&>(a);
    return b.n;
}

struct C : public A, public B { int p; };

void g() {
    C c;
    c.n = 2;
    // The dynamic_cast in f will be a successful "sideways cast"
    // from the A base subobject of c to the B base subobject of c.
    assert(f(c) == 2);
}
```

> As far as I've understood, The type of each class is stored as a string and whenever someone uses `dynamic_cast`, it compares the strings of types until it finds the right class. If that's true, why this is done? Why not giving each class an integer ID at compile time and storing that ID instead of the string name. And whenever casting happens, just compare the two numbers.

This wouldn't easily work because of the separate compilation model used by C++. Say Alice compiles her file a.cpp which defines some polymorphic classes. The compiler would need to choose some IDs for those classes. Meanwhile, Bob is a developer on NiftyLib, and adds a new feature, meaning that file b.cpp in NiftyLib source has some new polymorphic classes. His feature is ready for release, so the library project compiles b.cpp and other sources into library files, which are made available for developers. This will mean choosing some IDs for those classes. Alice's a.cpp is part of a program which uses NiftyLib, so she upgrades to the newer NiftyLib version. Making Alice's complete program involves linking the previously compiled a.cpp and the NiftyLib library file. But how could those compilers have chosen unique IDs so that none of the classes from a.cpp and b.cpp happen to share the same ID?

So I think some implementations of `dynamic_cast` do compare some mangled type name found via the RTTI, possibly the same C-string data returned by [`std::type_info::name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name). But not all. On Itanium ABI systems (see below), the compiler and linker can set things up to guarantee that there's just one RTTI data object (which is also the `std::type_info` object) per type, even if duplicate objects were originally emitted from different translation units. Then when code requests `dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr)`, the compiler will pass the known RTTI object for `T` and the RTTI object obtained via a vptr in `*ptr` to the internal support function implementing `dynamic_cast`. When that function is searching the tree of linked RTTI objects, it can then just compare addresses of the RTTI objects rather than checking any of their contents match.

For tons of the technical details, you can look at the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html), used on Linux, Mac, and several other platforms. In particular, section 2.9 is all about RTTI, with 2.9.4 specifying all the contents of an RTTI object and 2.9.7 describing how that data is used to implement `dynamic_cast` (in the truly dynamic case). The last I looked at it, the RTTI data scheme used by MSVC was fairly similar, just different in the details.